# Why is this Rewrite rule in my .htaccess file on Apache causing a 500 Internal Error?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here is the rule that is causing a 500 error. When I remove it, my site functions fine. Ideas?

```
RewriteRule ^pin/([^]+)/ pin.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an incorrect regex here `[^]+`. Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^pin/([^/]+)/?$ /pin.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```